# What does “not the less so" mean in this very complicated sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, syntax

I am extremely puzzled by the use and meaning of "**not the less so**" in this sentence. Does "so" refer to "resigned"? Could anyone help me with it please? Many thanks!

**The context is that Collins' proposal has just been refused by Elizabeth.**

Here is the sentence:

> Elizabeth passed quietly out of the room, Jane and Kitty followed, but
>   Lydia stood her ground, determined to hear all she could. And
>   Charlotte, detained first by the civility of Mr. Collins, whose
>   enquiries after herself and all her family were very minute, and then
>   by a little curiosity, satisfied herself with walking to the window
>   and pretending not to hear. In a doleful voice Mrs. Bennet thus began
>   the projected conversation, “Oh! Mr. Collins!”
>
> “My dear madam,” replied he, “let us be for ever silent on this point.
>   Far be it from me,” he presently continued in a voice that marked his
>   displeasure, “to resent the behaviour of your daughter. Resignation to
>   inevitable evils is the duty of us all, the peculiar duty of a young
>   man who has been so fortunate as I have been in early preferment. And
>   I trust I am resigned. **Perhaps not the less so from feeling a doubt
>   of my positive happiness had my fair cousin honoured me with her hand,
>   for I have often observed that resignation is never so perfect as when
>   the blessing denied begins to lose somewhat of its value in our
>   estimation.** You will not, I hope, consider me as showing any
>   disrespect to your family, my dear madam, by thus withdrawing my
>   pretensions to your daughter’s favour, without having paid yourself
>   and Mr. Bennet the compliment of requesting you to interpose your
>   authority in my behalf. My conduct may, I fear, be objectionable in
>   having accepted my dismission from your daughter’s lips instead of
>   your own. But we are all liable to error. I have certainly meant well
>   through the whole affair. My object has been to secure an amiable
>   companion for myself, with due consideration for the advantage of all
>   your family, and if my manner has been at all reprehensible, I here
>   beg leave to apologise.”
>
> *from Pride and Prejudice, by Jane Austen*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *so* refers to *resigned.* He is saying, in a very convoluted manner, that he feels *more* resigned to Lizzy's refusal because he is beginning to think she wouldn't have suited him anyway.

BTW, it's Austen with an 'e'!

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks.